# Getting all words out of a string

Tags: string, kotlin, arraylist

I have this arrayList that receives data dynamically from a database

```
val deviceNameList = arrayListOf<String>()
```

Getting the index 0 of the arraylist ie `deviceNameList[0]` prints a string of such a format:
[Peter, James]

How can i list all names in deviceNameList[0] individually.

Comment: Confirm that if it prints Peter,James or [Peter,James]?

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar I have checked it prints [Peter, James]. And if i use for each in trying the items it  [, p, e, t, e, ... etc which confirms the full thing is a String.

Comment: Great, then the answer given by Tim will solve your problem. The last line is only for print statements. First 2 line is solution for your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input string is `[Peter, James]`, you could try removing the square brackets at both ends, then regex splitting on comma followed by optional whitespace.

```
String input = "[Peter, James]";
String[] names = input.substring(1, input.length()-1).split(",\\s*");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
```

This prints:

```
[Peter, James]
```

Note that Java itself places square brackets around the array contents in `Arrays.toString`.  They are not part of the actual data.